# PatchRequest not working spring boot & angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, patch

java controller :

```
        @Autowired
        private BidPerContestService bidPerContestService;

        @Autowired
        private ContestService contestService;

        @Autowired
        private TeamService teamService;

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
        
        @PatchMapping("/patch/{id}/{teamN}/{userN}/{contestN}")
        public void patchBid(@PathVariable(name = "contestN") String contestN,
                             @PathVariable(name = "id") long id,
                             @PathVariable(name = "teamN") String teamN,
                             @PathVariable(name = "userN") String userN) {


          Contest contest = contestService.getContestByName(contestN);
          Team team = teamService.getTeam(teamN);
          User user = userService.getUserByEmail(userN);

          bidPerContestService.patchBidOnContest(id,team,user,contest);

        }
        
         @GetMapping("/last")
        public Object getLastBid()
        {
           return bidPerContestService.getBidsOfContest().toArray()            [bidPerContestService.getBidsOfContest().toArray().length-1];
        }
```

angular form submit function :

```
    addBetOnTeam() {

       this.http.post((this.bidUrl),this.bidCreateForm.value).subscribe(result => {

                  console.log(result);
                  console.log(this.bidCreateForm.value);

                });



        this.http.get(this.bidUrl+'/last').subscribe((result)=>
          {
              console.log(result);
              this.last = result;

              console.log(this.last.id);

              console.log(this.getUser());

              this.http.patch((this.bidUrl+'/patch/'+ this.last.id + '/' + this.objectList[0].teams[0].name + '/' + this.getUser() + '/' + this.objectList[0].name),null).subscribe(result=>console.log(result));

          });



        console.log(this.http.get(this.bidUrl+"/last").subscribe);
      }
```

The patch request url get's formed correctly, having containing the names of all the path variables and works as it should, but the data base stays the same. No errors, what's wrong with my patch request?

```
     this.http.patch((this.bidUrl+'/patch/'+ this.last.id + '/' + this.objectList[0].teams[0].name + '/' + this.getUser() + '/' + this.objectList[0].name),null).subscribe(result=>console.log(result));
```

URL of patch request is formed accordingly to the structure required by the controller.

form should output an object with a single attribute, named bid and used to work, now outputs 0 but might be related to patch error, or not, not a priority but a thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Could you please add the error you are getting to the question? It would be great to also have the console log and the HTTP request error details from your browser

Answer (score 0):

You might want to order the requests and to add some error handling.

I will guess this one `his.http.get(this.bidUrl+'/last')` should be hit only after this one `this.http.get(this.bidUrl+'/last')` finishes processing

To enforce the order let us do this:

```
this.http.post((this.bidUrl),this.bidCreateForm.value).subscribe(result => {
  ...
  this.http.get(this.bidUrl+'/last').subscribe(result2 => {
    ...
  })
})
```

To add error handling, we add this pipe to all requests:

```
.pipe(catchError(err => {
  console.error(err);
  return throwError(() => err);
}))
```

also, this log entry should be removed, as it will report a subscription id `console.log(this.http.get(this.bidUrl+"/last").subscribe);`, and that does not look like what you are after

So a proposed change to help you with progressing

```
addBetOnTeam() {
    console.log(this.bidUrl);
    this.http
        .post(this.bidUrl, this.bidCreateForm.value)
        .pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                console.error(err);
                return throwError(() => err);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(result1 => {
            console.log(result1);
            console.log(this.bidCreateForm.value);

            const request2Url = `${this.bidUrl}/last`;
            console.log(request2Url);
            this.http
                .get(request2Url)
                .pipe(
                    catchError(err => {
                        console.error(err);
                        return throwError(() => err);
                    })
                )
                .subscribe(result2 => {
                    console.log(result2);
                    this.last = result2;

                    console.log(this.last.id);

                    console.log(this.getUser());

                    const request3Url = `${this.bidUrl}/patch/${this.last.id}/${this.objectList[0].teams[0].name}/${this.getUser()}/${this.objectList[0].name}`;

                    console.log(request3Url);

                    this.http
                        .patch(request3Url, null)
                        .pipe(
                            catchError(err => {
                                console.error(err);
                                return throwError(() => err);
                            })
                        )
                        .subscribe(result3 => console.log(result3));
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response @TheFabio my initial code had no errors, but the values in mySql table didn`t change, i tried your version and the patch returned 200, but when i look at my sql table the values appear as null, like before.

Comment: If this code is sending the correct values (you can check the sent request in your browser's dev tools) The problem will be on the Back-end code